# App Delegate Object

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

In my appdelegate I have declared an object of a custom class I developed.  And in my view controller I have added the following lines of code:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate.dbConnector loadImages:self];
```

There are no errors, however even though the compiler processes the loadImages, it will not enter the function.  I have used breakpoints to check this.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Check you have intialize and set properly for "dbConnector" object. This may be issue.

Comment: in my app delegate I have declared in both the header file and interface file with `@synthesize dbConnector;`

Answer (score 1):

Your `dbConnector` property is likely nil.  Make sure you are setting an instance to that property.  You can send any message to a nil so you won't get any warnings or errors.  Your `dbConnector` property is defaulted to nil until you assign it something.

Comment: in my app delegate I have declared in both the header file and interface file with `@synthesize dbConnector;`

Comment: Yes..you declared the property.  Now, where do you set that property to an instance of that class?  I would assume you would do `self.dbConnector = [MyConnectorClass alloc] init] autorelease];` in your app delegate's init method or similar.  That property will default to nil until you set it to some living object.  This is programming 101.

Comment: Show me what the property looks like in your header file.

Comment: `@property (nonatomic, retain) dbInterface *dbConnector;`

Comment: Good, now, where do you assign dbConnector an instance of dbInterface?  Somewhere you need to set that property with something.  Show that code. It should look something _similar_ to this: `appDelegate.dbConnector = [[dbInterface alloc] init] autorelease];`

Comment: Then be sure that line of code executes before you place a call to loadImages.

Comment: i have this `dbInterface *dbConnector=[[dbInterface alloc]init];
    dbConnector.managedObjectContext=self.managedObjectContext;` in my app delegate in `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and i get the error that i am hiding a instance variable

Answer (score -2):

```
[appDelegate.dbConnector loadImages:appDelegate];
```